# Any way to login with email address in EE 3?

Tags: login, ee3, solspace-user

I'm working on a site where login with email is requested. NSM Email Login is only for EE2, and although the site is using User from Solspace, their solution to copy the email address into the username is inadequate for this site's needs.

Is there any other way to permit login with email address in EE3?

Answer (score 1):

The "User" 4.0.7 plugin from Solspace supports it.

You can find it at https://solspace.com/expressionengine/user/docs/email_as_username/

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using email instead of username ?

Replace this

```
<input type="text" name="username" />
```

to this :

```
<input type="email" name="email" />
```